# Mongo Query to modify the existing field value with new value + array of objects

Tags: arrays, mongodb, crud

I want to update many documents based on the condition in MongoDB.

MODEL is the collection which has the document with below information.

```
    "info": [
      {
        "field1": "String1",
        "field2": "String2"
      },
      {
        "field1": "String1",
        "field2": "String_2"
      }
    ],
    "var": "x"
```

I need to update all the "String1" value of field1 with "STRING_NEW". I used the below query to update but not working as expected.

```
 db.model.updateMany(
         { "info.field1": { $exists: true } },
        [
            { "$set": { 
                "info": {
                    "$map": {
                        "input": "$info.field1",
                        "in": {
                            "$cond": [
                                { "$eq": ["$$this.field1", "String1"] }, 
                                 "STRING_NEW",
                                  $$this.field1
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            } }
        ]
    )
```

Please have a look and suggest if anything is to be modified in the above query.

Comment: Does your actual document contain `model` field? Based on your update query, it won't find any document as the provided document doesn't contain `info` field in the root (the `info` field is nested, within the `model` object).

Comment: Thanks for asking the question. I corrected my question. Model is the collection name and one of the document i mentioned it in JSON format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1**

With the update with aggregation pipeline, you should iterate the object in `info` array and update the iterated object by merging the current object with new `field1` field via `$mergeObjects`.

```
db.model.updateMany({
  "info.field1": "String1"
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "info": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$info",
          "in": {
            "$cond": [
              {
                "$eq": [
                  "$$this.field1",
                  "String1"
                ]
              },
              {
                $mergeObjects: [
                  "$$this",
                  {
                    "field1": "STRING_NEW"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo Solution 1 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/D-m8TLp0y6E)

---

**Solution 2**

Can also work with [`$[<identifier>]` positional filtered operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) and `arrayFilters`.

```
db.model.updateMany({
  "info.field1": "String1"
},
{
  "$set": {
    "info.$[info].field1": "STRING_NEW"
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "info.field1": "String1"
    }
  ]
})
```

[Demo Solution 2 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gMMbItaJsR6)